# Historificar una tabla de base de datos en SQL pero con la hora en zona horaria GMT+2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLA_EJEMPLO
(
[Id] INT,
[Fecha_Inicio_Sistema] DATETIME2 (7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL, 
[Fecha_Fin_Sistema] DATETIME2 (7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999',

CONSTRAINT [TABLA_EJEMPLO_PK] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([Fecha_Inicio_Sistema], [Fecha_Fin_Sistema])) ON [PRIMARY] 
WITH(SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON ( HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[TBB2EntidadDocumento_Hist] )
)
```

Esta tabla ya está historificada, el problema es que cuando hago inserts o update sobre los registros de esta tabla, la hora que me genera es dos horas anterior a la hora actual (Como si la zona horaria fuera UTC).

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer que la tabla se historifique con la hora actual? (Zona horaria GMT+2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Esto no es posible**, de acuerdo a la [documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables), las horas utilizadas en las columnas utilizadas para el período de las tablas temporales **están siempre en zona horaria UTC**.

Por ejemplo, dice para la operación de inserción:

> NSERTS: el sistema establece el valor de la columna ValidFrom en la hora de inicio de la transacción actual (**en la zona horaria UTC**) según el reloj del sistema y asigna el valor de la columna ValidTo al valor máximo de 31-12-9999. Esto marca la fila como abierta.

El resaltado es mío.

La misma documentación sigue mencionando la zona horaria UTC para el resto de operaciones: `update`, `delete`, `merge`.

Además, el artículo [Escenarios de uso de tablas temporales](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-table-usage-scenarios) dice también:

> Las tablas temporales con versión del sistema almacenan valores para columnas de período **en la zona horaria UTC**, aunque comprobará que es más conveniente trabajar con la zona horaria local, tanto para filtrar datos como para mostrar resultados. En el ejemplo de código siguiente se muestra cómo aplicar la condición de filtrado, que originalmente se ha especificado en la zona horaria local y después se ha convertido a UTC mediante la cláusula AT TIME ZONE introducida en SQL Server 2016

De nuevo el resaltado es mío.

El artículo da el siguiente ejemplo de uso, que te puede orientar para trabajar tus consultas partiendo de fecha y horas locales:

```sql
DECLARE @asOf DATETIMEOFFSET = GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'
/*Convert AS OF filter to UTC*/
SET @asOf = DATEADD (HOUR, -9, @asOf) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';

SELECT
    EmployeeID
    , Name
    , Position
    , Department
    , [Address]
    , [AnnualSalary]
    , ValidFrom AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AS ValidFromPT
    , ValidTo AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AS ValidToPT
FROM Employee
    FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF @asOf where EmployeeId = 1000;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, había visto esto...  pero bueno, había que probar... a ver si sonaba la flauta, modificaré las queries para que la query si que devuelva la hora que tiene que devolver.

Comment: Edité la respuesta para dejarte un ejemplo, justo pensando que tendrías que modificar las consultas. Por favor actualiza y dale una nueva leída, de pronto te ayuda. Un saludo.